# QEMU cannot boot locally built Linux kernel anymore

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, qemu

Since yesterday, I can no longer launch `qemu` with an external kernel compiled on my laptop (running Arch Linux).

If I compile a vanilla Linux kernel (version 4.13, from Linus Torvalds' github repo), then try to boot `qemu` this way:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -boot c -kernel arch/x86/boot/bzImage
```

This starts the display, showing this SeaBIOS output refreshing every 2-3 seconds:

```
   Booting from ROM...
   Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
   early console in extract_kernel
   input_data: 0x0000000002c773b4
   input_len: 0x000000000090c470
   output: 0x0000000001000000
   output_len: 0x000000000173a968
   kernel_total_size: 0x00000000025a7000

   Decompressing Linux... Parsing ELF...
```

If I add these flags to `qemu` to enable SeaBIOS debugging output:

```
-chardev stdio,id=seabios -device isa-debugcon,iobase=0x402,chardev=seabios
```

I get this output that keeps repeating: https://pastebin.com/mZKeM6r5

Funny thing, if I compile the same kernel, with the same configuration file on another machine (running Debian) and copy the `bzImage` to my machine, it boots just fine. So I guess something happened in my toolchain. There was an update of `gcc` recently, but going back to the previous version of the package (the one I had when there was no problem) does not solve my problem.

As a temporary workaround, I thought I could compile on the Debian machine using `distcc` to avoid copying files back and forth, but the problem still occurs, so I guess the problem is in the final steps of the compilation process (from linkage to the end, since these happen on my laptop).

Additional info:

- `gcc` version on my laptop (ArchLinux): 8.2.0 (pkg version = 8.2.0-2)
- `gcc` version on my Debian machine: 6.3.0 (pkg version = 4:6.3.0-4)

---

**Edit**: completed SeaBIOS output

Comment: Are you rebuilding the same sources after switching toolchains?  If so, did you do a `make clean` before the rebuild with the new toolchain?

Comment: @AndyDalton: yes. But the problem was there even when only using my local toolchain (I built nothing, everything comes from the archlinux package repositories)

Comment: The output from pastebin shows that [the VM is trying to resume from the S3 power state.](https://github.com/CoreSecurity/pycodin/blob/master/qemu-0.12.3/roms/seabios/src/resume.c) What happens if you force a full shutdown of the VM?

Comment: @ErikF: If I try to force a shutdown, it keeps rebooting, but I guess it never catches the shutdown signal since it's already rebooting. Also, the source code you linked to is an old version of seabios. I checked the source of the version my `qemu` uses (the same as [here](https://github.com/coreboot/seabios/blob/master/src/resume.c)), and it looks like `handle_resume()` is called with a status value of 0 (as in the output), which calls `handle_resume32()`, then `tryReboot()` and `qemu` reboots.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is likely with an auto-generated setting based on compiler version/architecture then. In `General setup`, what do you have for the compiler optimization level? Did you enable any GCC plugins? What is `Stack protector buffer overflow detection` set to? Also, in `Processor type and features`, what is the selected processor family?

Comment: Compiler optimization is set to `Optimize for performance`, stack protector to `None`, and processor type is `Generic x86-64`. But I don't knw if it is really this kind of problem, since rolling back to the previous version of the `gcc`package (which used to work correctly) did not fix the problem, with no change to the configuration file and to my `qemu` setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was caused by the binutils update to 2.31. Judging from the date you posted your question, it's not unlikely that you had just installed the arch linux binutils update to 2.31 from August 2nd, which matches nicely.

You need [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip.git/commit/?id=e3d03598e8ae7d195af5d3d049596dec336f569f) for kernels earlier than 4.16.

binutils 2.31 has changed the defaults of the linker (`ld`) such that the default for [max-page-size](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) was decreased from 2MiB to 4kiB. This change breaks the x86_64 kernel, unless said commit is applied.

Comment: This answer had a low score, but upvoting and commenting as this worked for me. Thank you very much.